# What's the problem with this code? [hashtable in C]

Tags: c, hashtable

I'm implementing a hash table. The following is my function for initializing it.
Im getting some errors which I cant understand why. I have also quoted what valgrind says.

```
 typedef struct HashTable
    {
     int size ;  
     struct List *head; 
     struct List *tail;     
    }HashTable;

    typedef struct List
    {
     char *number;
     char *name;
     int time;
     struct List *next;     
    }List;

    #define size_of_table 211

    HashTable *createHashTable(void)
    {
     HashTable *new_table = malloc(sizeof(*new_table)*size_of_table); //line 606

     if (new_table == NULL)
     { return NULL;
     }

     int i=0;
     for(i; i<size_of_table; i++)
     { 
      new_table[i].size=0;
      new_table[i].head=NULL;
      new_table[i].tail=NULL;
     }
     return NULL;
    }
```

> ```
> Invalid write of size 8
> ==7738==    at 0x401707: createHashTable (project2.c:617)
> ==7738==    by 0x401AF6: main (project.c:739)
> ==7738==  Address 0x51996e0 is 8 bytes after a block of size 1,688 alloc'd
> ==7738==    at 0x4C25153: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:195)
> ==7738==    by 0x401698: createHashTable (project2.c:606)
> ==7738==    by 0x401AF6: main (project.c:739)
> ==7738== 
> ==7738== 
> ==7738== 141 errors in context 3 of 4:
> ==7738== Invalid write of size 8
> ==7738==    at 0x4016E8: createHashTable (project2.c:616)
> ==7738==    by 0x401AF6: main (project.c:739)
> ==7738==  Address 0x51996d8 is 0 bytes after a block of size 1,688 alloc'd
> ==7738==    at 0x4C25153: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:195)
> ==7738==    by 0x401698: createHashTable (project2.c:606)
> ==7738==    by 0x401AF6: main (project.c:739)
> ```

Comment: @SLaks. I have defined it in the starting of the program. It's an integer number.

Comment: See [memset(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memset), or [bzero(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/bzero).

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me. I added `const int size_of_table = 12` and invoked `createHashTable()` from `main`.

```
$ valgrind ./a.out 
==30237== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==30237== Copyright (C) 2002-2009, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==30237== Using Valgrind-3.6.0.SVN and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==30237== Command: ./a.out
==30237== 
--30237-- ./a.out:
--30237-- dSYM directory is missing; consider using --dsymutil=yes
==30237== 
==30237== HEAP SUMMARY:
==30237==     in use at exit: 376 bytes in 2 blocks
==30237==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 0 frees, 376 bytes allocated
==30237== 
==30237== LEAK SUMMARY:
==30237==    definitely lost: 288 bytes in 1 blocks
==30237==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==30237==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==30237==    still reachable: 88 bytes in 1 blocks
==30237==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==30237== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==30237== 
==30237== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==30237== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
$
```

Comment: Berger I've tried also with 12 as u said,but it's still the same!

Answer (score 1):

Are you *sure* that's the code you're testing? 1688 bytes divided into 211 array elements gives 8 bytes each.

It's rather unlikely that a modern environment would only give you 8 bytes for a structure holding an `int` and two pointers.

---

By way of testing, the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct HashTable {
    int size ;
    struct List *head;
    struct List *tail;
} HashTable;

typedef struct List {
    char *number;
    char *name;
    int time;
    struct List *next;
} List;

#define size_of_table 211

HashTable *createHashTable(void) {
    HashTable *new_table = malloc(sizeof(*new_table)*size_of_table); //line 606
    printf ("%d\n", sizeof(*new_table));
    printf ("%d\n", sizeof(new_table));
    if (new_table == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    int i=0;
    for(i; i<size_of_table; i++) {
        new_table[i].size=0;
        new_table[i].head=NULL;
        new_table[i].tail=NULL;
    }
    return new_table;
}

int main(void) {
    HashTable *x = createHashTable();
    free (x);
    return 0;
}
```

outputs:

```
==3569== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==3569== Copyright (C) 2002-2009, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==3569== Using Valgrind-3.6.0.SVN-Debian and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==3569== Command: ./qq
==3569== 
12
4
==3569== 
==3569== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3569==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3569==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 2,532 bytes allocated
==3569== 
==3569== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==3569== 
==3569== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==3569== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 13 from 8)
```

What does that program give you when you run it through valgrind on your system?

That code I supply above also fixes your problem with returning NULL on success by the way (a definite memory leak). Your final return in the function should not be returning NULL, it should be:

```
    return new_table;
```

---

Based on your `24,8` output from the sample code I provided, make sure you're *really* using:

```
    HashTable *new_table = malloc(sizeof(*new_table)*size_of_table); //line 606
```

rather than:

```
    HashTable *new_table = malloc(sizeof(new_table)*size_of_table); //line 606
```

The latter will use the pointer size of `8` rather than the structure size of `24` and, when I do it that way, I get:

```
==3637== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==3637== Copyright (C) 2002-2009, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==3637== Using Valgrind-3.6.0.SVN-Debian and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==3637== Command: ./qq
==3637== 
12
4
==3637== Invalid write of size 4
==3637==    at 0x80484CD: createHashTable (in /home/allan/qq)
==3637==    by 0x8048509: main (in /home/allan/qq)
==3637==  Address 0x419a374 is 0 bytes after a block of size 844 alloc'd
==3637==    at 0x4024F20: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
==3637==    by 0x8048465: createHashTable (in /home/allan/qq)
==3637==    by 0x8048509: main (in /home/allan/qq)
==3637== 
==3637== Invalid write of size 4
==3637==    at 0x80484E3: createHashTable (in /home/allan/qq)
==3637==    by 0x8048509: main (in /home/allan/qq)
==3637==  Address 0x419a378 is 4 bytes after a block of size 844 alloc'd
==3637==    at 0x4024F20: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
==3637==    by 0x8048465: createHashTable (in /home/allan/qq)
==3637==    by 0x8048509: main (in /home/allan/qq)
==3637== 
==3637== Invalid write of size 4
==3637==    at 0x80484B8: createHashTable (in /home/allan/qq)
==3637==    by 0x8048509: main (in /home/allan/qq)
==3637==  Address 0x419a37c is 8 bytes after a block of size 844 alloc'd
==3637==    at 0x4024F20: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
==3637==    by 0x8048465: createHashTable (in /home/allan/qq)
==3637==    by 0x8048509: main (in /home/allan/qq)
==3637== 
==3637== 
==3637== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3637==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3637==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 844 bytes allocated
==3637== 
==3637== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==3637== 
==3637== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==3637== ERROR SUMMARY: 422 errors from 3 contexts (suppressed: 13 from 8)
```

---

If you are sure you're using the `24` value, place the line:

```
printf ("%d\n", sizeof(*new_table)*size_of_table);
```

after the `malloc` line and see what it outputs.

Comment: to tell the truth,i just tested on a random number first. :/

Comment: Are you sure your malloc statement isn't `sizeof(new_table)*size_of_table` (ie. the size of the pointer rather than the content)? That would be 8 rather than 24.

Comment: no i checked it. it's: malloc(sizeof(*new_table)*size_of_table);

Comment: is there any case that this memory is allocated? cause valgring gives: Searching for pointers to 1 not-freed blocks

Comment: And it still maintains that the allocated block was 1688 bytes? Try using `sizeof(HashTable)` rather than `sizeof(*new_table)` in the malloc (humor me). Then, work _just_ with the code I provided above in a single source file and tell us the exact output. That should remove any tricky aspects of your problem that I don't yet know about :-)

Comment: paxdiablo...i think that i fixed it with your help. problem is...that appeared another error on the hashcode :/

Comment: well, running only your code,it gives 24,8! maybe operating system makes the difference? :/ also to note that even it's sizeof(new_table)*size_of_table OR   sizeof(*new_table)*size_of_table OR sizeof(HashTable)*size_of_table   it gives the same results!

Comment: @paxdiablo. Im sorry if i bother u,but just because i have a query and i dont wanna post again. With the selected size_of_table is it possible to have a hashvalue like 53074??? As the table has only 211 buckets how can i put a value on its 53074th bucket? Do hash functions normally provide such numbers? Or not?

Comment: @FILIaS, that would actually depend on your hash function which you haven't provided so it's a little hard to comment intelligently - that won't _stop_ me from commenting of course :-) I'll give you one option here: if you take your hash value and mod it by the bucket size, you'll get a value you can use: `actual_bucket_number = hash_value % size_of_table;` for example. But I still suggest asking another question if you feel up to it. As my wife will tell you (frequently and at great length), I've been wrong before :-)

Comment: thnx paxdiablo! well i use Cyclic shift hash codes and use the mod too in order to get the number. I was just curious how can this happen as the bucket size is 211 but i get really high hashvalues. where the datas will be stored then? all in the last bucket??